# Begin keyword related error in date difference procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

compliation is successful but when i execute this code its showing error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'" ..and is it possible follwing code

```
SET @TEMPSELECT=(SELECT Cast(Abs(Datediff(day, @EndDate, @StartDate)) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS day)

PRINT @TEMPSELECT
```

[procedure date difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ifre.jpg)

Comment: please refer image that i attached

Comment: Is this a sql-server proc?

Comment: yes its related to sql server

Comment: Which version are you using

Comment: i think you are trying to execute the sp right after the End keyword. try to put a go statement before you execute the sp

Comment: I am using the oracle sql developer ..i tried your code but still  i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Prc_datechecking
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME='04/07/2015',
              @EndDate    DATETIME='04/09/2015',
              @TEMPSELECT NVARCHAR(50)=''

      SET @TEMPSELECT=(SELECT Cast(Abs(Datediff(day, @EndDate, @StartDate)) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS day)

      PRINT @TEMPSELECT
  END

EXEC Prc_datechecking
```

This works fine in SQL Server 2012